# finder search window – functionality of keyboard shortcut changes

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, shortcut, sidebar

I use cmd + alt + spacebar to launch a new finder window on my mac. Sometimes however, instead of launching a normal finder window complete with sidebar ([something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk5tC.jpg)), it instead launches a window without a sidebar, like this [image]. Why does this happen and how do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: btw, CMD+ALT+Space is pretty cool for opening a new search window.  You can also open a new Finder window with CMD+SHIFT+N, and use the Finder Prefs to choose what folder is shown in new windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my computer, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> toggles the toolbars on/off. 
Maybe you have this keyboard shortcut set to <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd> + `M`,`N`,`B`,`V`, or `C`, such that you accidentally hit both shortcuts?

You can check in your `SysPrefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts` pane, or just try those shortcuts that are near the space bar.

I suggest this because of your assertion that it happens "*sometimes*", which is pretty weird.  I did once have my toolbars *always* missing, which it turns out required some preference file to be deleted or something.  But I've never seen an intermittent issue like that.